# How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing a list of strings. Each string is made up of several words, but the number of words in each string is different.

Using built in Excel functions (no VBA), is there a way to isolate the last word in each string?

Examples:

```
  Are you classified as human? -> human?
Negative, I am a meat popsicle -> popsicle
                  Aziz! Light! -> Light!
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you have the artificial no VBA constraint?

Comment: I can easily solve it with VBA, but I'm curious if there is a non-VBA solution. VBA tends to have performance penalties for large data sets.

Comment: As usual, two answers really stand out, and I have a tough time deciding which one to select as the correct answer. In this case, both Jon and BradC (with the help of Brad) have come up with correct, working solutions.

Comment: I have selected BradC's solution because it seems to be the more elegant of the two, and he provides a handy explanation of the function.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question properly if you don't indicate what makes VBA inappropriate (since you can write your own macros and functions in VBA, making it equivalent to the built-in functions).

Comment: @le dorfier: see my comment above

Comment: One thing I will say, is that the reason it is better to use formulae over VBA is because you stay a .xslx. Once you write a line of VBA, you become a .xlsm and a potential security threat that could write to any COM port, registry; open applications; yada yada - VBA is integrated throughout windows - to any virus checker, email client; or application that tries to open it. So, staying in "spreadsheet land" adds a lot of value to the average "security conscious user". That's why Lamdba functions are so powerful, they bring you a step closer to VBA without making your doc a security threat.

Comment: With functions you have just processed the data - however "elegantly" - with vba you could have reaped "the whirlwind" or created "paradise". Which you chose: was up to you. Sometimes, "keeping it simple" is the most elegant solution of all.

Comment: and further to @MikeParks, O365 can't cope with VBA if you're using web excel or teams excel

Comment: Too bad this couldn't be as simple as in PHP, where if you give it a negative start point it searches backwards.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

This one is tested and does work (based on Brad's original post):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",
     LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

If your original strings could contain a pipe "|" character, then replace both in the above with some other character that won't appear in your source. (I suspect Brad's original was broken because an unprintable character was removed in the translation).

Bonus: How it works (from right to left):

`LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` – Count of spaces in the original string
`SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|", ... )` – Replaces just the *final* space with a `|`
`FIND("|", ... )` – Finds the absolute position of that replaced `|` (that was the final space)
`Right(A1,LEN(A1) - ... ))` – Returns all characters after that `|`

**EDIT:** to account for the case where the source text contains no spaces, add the following to the beginning of the formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1, ... )
```

making the entire formula now:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1, RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - FIND("|",
    SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))))
```

Or you can use the `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"* *")` syntax of the other version.

When the original string might contain a space at the last position add a trim function while counting all the spaces: Making the function the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",B2)),B2, RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2) - FIND("|",
    SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",LEN(TRIM(B2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))))
```

Comment: Cannot thank you enough.  Needed the rest of the string too, so simply changing =RIGHT to =LEFT and removing LEN(A1)- allowed me to get the rest.  But thank you for doing all the initial leg work :)

Comment: +1: I'll have to remember the "LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))" trick for getting the number of instances of a character

Comment: Excellent solution! The only problem is that Excel localizes function names, so you need to re-write the formula for the non-English Excel. Here is the re-written variant for the Russian one: =ПРАВСИМВ(A1;ДЛСТР(A1)-ПОИСК("|";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"|";ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"")))))

Comment: This answer breaks on strings containing consecutive spaces.

Comment: I would recommend breaking up the formulas into temporary columns (you can hide them later). It's very useful for debugging special cases.

Comment: If Someone needs the solution in German:  =RECHTS(A1;LÄNGE(A1)-FINDEN("#";WECHSELN(A1;" ";"#";LÄNGE(A1)-LÄNGE(WECHSELN(A1;" ";"")))))

Comment: And here is the Portuguese version: =DIREITA(A1;NÚM.CARACT(A1)-PROCURAR("|";SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"|"; NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1;" ";"")))))

Comment: to put [@marcelo's translation for PT-BR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313566/3501748) with the ones above
`=SE(ÉERRO(PROCURAR("\",A1)),A1,DIREITA(A1,NÚM.CARACT(A1)-PROCURAR("|",SUBSTITUIR(A1,"\","|",NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1,"\",""))))))`

Answer (score 95):

This is the technique I've used with great success:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

To get the first word in a string, just change from RIGHT to LEFT

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

Also, replace A1 by the cell holding the text.

Comment: Works for me - just replaced the first `" "` with my delimiter. The two `100`s seem to limit it to a string of 100 characters if I'm not mistaken

Comment: If we use a different delimiter we need to strip that out at the end too, e.g. `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", REPT(".", 100)), 100), ".", ""))`

Comment: Very clever method. What it does is replace every space with 100 spaces, then return the last 100 characters without leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: @Benjineer I think it works for strings much longer than 100 characters. The 100 characters limits the size of a single word. You're taking the right (or left) hundred characters ..... if a word of 101 characters long you'd have a problem, but if a string overall of 100 characters ... with 3 spaces ... would be padded to approx a 400 character string and still work.     To Jerry Beaucaire - Very elegant, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

A more robust version of Jerry's answer:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", REPT(" ", LEN(TRIM(A1)))), LEN(TRIM(A1))))
```

That works regardless of the length of the string, leading or trailing spaces, or whatever else and it's still pretty short and simple.

Comment: It's an excellent formula. I modified the formula to `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), ".", REPT(" ", LEN(TRIM(A1)))), LEN(TRIM(A1))))` to get file extension.

Comment: One more `SUBSTITUTE` allows it to work for any character, not just spaces. `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),"/",REPT("/",LEN(TRIM(A1)))),LEN(TRIM(A1))),"/",""))`, where "/" is the delimiting character.

Comment: @Joefinkle, this is a really concise and smart solution. It works pretty well, just to mention that if the delimiter is a string it does not work well in all cases, here an example for a delimiter: `" ; "` (a semi-colon surrounded by spaces) with input value: `"Technology Sprint 24 ; Sprint 4"` it returns: `"; Sprint 4"`. I am using the solution addapted by: @PProteus.

Comment: If the delimiter is a string a possible workaround would be to replace it before by some special character, for example replacing in the @PProteus formula `TRIM(A1)` by: `TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "strDelimeter", ";"))` in all places, in order to have a new character delimiter:  `";"` or even better using `char()` function to find some really unexpected character.

Comment: @PProteus you don't need the `TRIM` function after adding the second `SUBSTITUTE` for the general case single character solution. The formula provides the expected result eliminating this part: `=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),";",REPT(";",LEN(TRIM(A1)))),LEN(TRIM(A1))),";","")`

Answer (score 13):

I found [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Excel/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/2006-09/msg02157.html) on google, tested in Excel 2003 & it works for me:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"* *"),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LOOKUP(LEN(A1),FIND(" ",A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1),1))))),A1)
```

[edit] I don't have enough rep to comment, so this seems the best place...BradC's answer also doesn't work with trailing spaces or empty cells...
[2nd edit] actually, it doesn't work for single words either...

Comment: Closest solution yet, but I would throw in a Trim() since a trailing space will break it.

Comment: True, probably easiest to trim() in an intermediate cell & then apply above formula to the intermediate cell.
Also, spits out 0 if the cell happens to be empty, so could also be wrapped with isblank()

Answer (score 5):

### New answer 9/28/2022

Considering the new excel function: [TEXTAFTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textafter-function-c8db2546-5b51-416a-9690-c7e6722e90b4) (check availability) you can achieve it with a simple formula:

```
=TEXTAFTER(A1," ", -1)
```

[image: sample excel]

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know this function existed.

Answer (score 3):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("`*`",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","`*`",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

Comment: Did you test it?  Doesn't work for me with "Are you classified as human?"

Comment: No, it does not work. Has some interesting elements, though.
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","") gives you the count of spaces in the string.

Comment: That is an interesting function. Too bad it doesn't work. I like the trick for being able to count the number of spaces.

Comment: @Brad: I edited your post to show the * characters. The original did not print them properly. With these in place, it does work. +1

Answer (score 3):

This is very clean and compact, and works well.

```
{=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW(1:999),1)=" ",ROW(1:999),0)))}
```

It does not error trap for no spaces or one word, but that's easy to add.

**Edit:**
This handles trailing spaces, single word, and empty cell scenarios. I have not found a way to break it.

```
{=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-MAX(IF(MID(TRIM(A1),ROW($1:$999),1)=" ",ROW($1:$999),0)))}
```

Comment: Cool. That is a really interesting use of array functions! I didn't expect to get another answer after such a long time. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-FIND(CHAR(7),SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM(A1)," ",CHAR(7),
LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM(A1)," ",""))+1))+1)
```

This is very robust--it works for sentences with no spaces, leading/trailing spaces, multiple spaces, multiple leading/trailing spaces... and I used char(7) for the delimiter rather than the vertical bar "|" just in case that is a desired text item.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jerry and Joe's answers, if you're wanting to find the text BEFORE the last word you can use:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", REPT(" ", LEN(TRIM(A1)))), LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", REPT(" ", LEN(TRIM(A1)))))-LEN(TRIM(A1))))
```

With 'My little cat' in A1 would result in 'My little' (where Joe and Jerry's would give 'cat'

In the same way that Jerry and Joe isolate the last word, this then just gets everything to the left of that (then trims it back)

Answer (score 2):

Copy into a column, select that column and HOME > Editing > Find & Select, Replace:

[image: Find what:]

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

There is a space after the asterisk.

Comment: Note that * is a (greedy) wildcard in excel searches, so this matches everything up to the last space and replaces it with nothing

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the string could be reversed. Then it is really easy. Instead of working on the string:

```
"My little cat" (1)
```

you work with

```
"tac elttil yM" (2)
```

With `=LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1)-1)` in A2 you get `"My"` with (1) and `"tac"` with (2), which is reversed `"cat"`, the last word in (1).

There are a few VBAs around to reverse a string. I prefer the public VBA function [`ReverseString`](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=188).

Install the above as described. Then with your string in A1, e.g., `"My little cat"` and this function in A2:

```
=ReverseString(LEFT(ReverseString(A1);IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ";A1));
  LEN(A1);(FIND(" ";ReverseString(A1))-1))))
```

you'll see `"cat"` in A2.

The method above assumes that words are separated by blanks. The `IF` clause is for cells containing single words = no blanks in cell. Note: `TRIM` and `CLEAN` the original string are useful as well. In principle it reverses the whole string from A1 and simply finds the first blank in the reversed string which is next to the last (reversed) word (i.e., `"tac "`). `LEFT` picks this word and another string reversal reconstitutes the original order of the word (`" cat"`). The `-1` at the end of the `FIND` statement removes the blank.

The idea is that it is easy to extract the first(!) word in a string with `LEFT` and `FIND`ing the first blank. However, for the last(!) word the `RIGHT` function is the wrong choice when you try to do that because unfortunately FIND does not have a flag for the direction you want to analyse your string.

Therefore the whole string is simply reversed. `LEFT` and `FIND` work as normal but the extracted string is reversed. But his is no big deal once you know how to reverse a string. The first `ReverseString` statement in the formula does this job.

Comment: That is so much simpler than all the other options here, thanks so much!! Why Find can't have a reverse find, or substitute - I seem to remember something to do with using a negative number to do reverse search, but clearly not vba....

Comment: The OP asked for no VBA.

Comment: Also thats insane! If you are going to use VBA you could just as easily have a reverse find

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(IF(
 ISERROR(
  FIND("_",A1)
 ),A1,RIGHT(A1,
  LEN(A1)-FIND("~",
   SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","~",
    LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))
   )
  )
 )
),A1,1)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I translated to PT-BR, as I needed this as well.

(Please note that I've changed the space to `\` because I needed the filename only of path strings.)

```
=SE(ÉERRO(PROCURAR("\",A1)),A1,DIREITA(A1,NÚM.CARACT(A1)-PROCURAR("|", SUBSTITUIR(A1,"\","|",NÚM.CARACT(A1)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A1,"\",""))))))
```

Comment: I don't know how to read Excel in Portuguese, so I'll have to take your word for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is as below

```
=IF(ISERROR(TRIM(MID(TRIM(D14),SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D14)," ","|",LEN(TRIM(D14))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D14)," ","")))),LEN(TRIM(D14))))),TRIM(D14),TRIM(MID(TRIM(D14),SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D14)," ","|",LEN(TRIM(D14))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D14)," ","")))),LEN(TRIM(D14)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this also by reversing the string and finding the first space

`=MID(C3,2+LEN(C3)-SEARCH(" ",CONCAT(MID(C3,SEQUENCE(LEN(C3),,LEN(C3),-1),1))),LEN(A1))`

1. Reverse the string

`CONCAT(MID(C3,SEQUENCE(LEN(C3),,LEN(C3),-1),1))`

2. Find the first space in the reversed string

`SEARCH(" ",...`

3. Take the position of the space found in the reversed string off the length of the string and return that portion

`=MID(C3,2+LEN(C3)-SEARCH...`

Answer (score -1):

I also had a task like this and when I was done, using the above method, a new method occured to me: Why don't you do this:

1. Reverse the string ("string one" becomes "eno gnirts").
2. Use the good old Find (which is hardcoded for left-to-right).
3. Reverse it into readable string again.

How does this sound?

Comment: Sure. But how do you reverse the string in Excel?