# Get parent folder path from file path using cell formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In column `A` I have 20000 rows with filename with file path

> "C:\person\microsoft\ygkyg\mmddyy\filename.xls"
>    "\server-41\performance\mmddyy\filename.doc"
>    .....
>   etc.

In column `B` I just want to get the parent folder path.

Could someone help me with the formula? I tried this but it's giving me the file name.

```
=MID(a1,FIND(CHAR(1),
    SUBSTITUTE(a1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(a1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(a1))
```

Comment: would you accept a VBA solution?

Comment: @David, Actually, I am just looking for simple excel formula.

Comment: @david I think a VBA solution would be the only sane one right? A `Mid()` from 1 to the last occurrence of "\" should work but have no idea how it would go with a formula!

Comment: @Hannah I don't think I can help you then. Good luck!

Comment: @hannah you can use a VBA function as a UDF formula.

Comment: I tried this but not working. =MID(B3,1+FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B3,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"\","")))),255)

Comment: @giddy. vba is disabled on the server.

Comment: =MID(CELL(B4),1,FIND("/",CELL(B4))-1) not working

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works.

`=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A1))))`

The above was my original answer. [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182705/neil) simplified the expression somewhat and posted this as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504797/get-parent-folder-path-from-file-path-using-cell-formula/5505006#comment6248961_5505006) below:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","?",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `?` is a forbidden character in paths so that `"?"` can safely be used instead of `CHAR(1)` as a placemark, thus improving readability a little bit. Also, `LEFT(A1,x)` is equivalent to, and shorter than `MID(A1,1,x)`, so it makes sense to use `LEFT`. But most importantly, this formula makes use of `FIND`, instead of a second layer of counting characters using `LEN`. This makes it *much* more readable.

Comment: Missed by a few seconds, good one Jean! FY, the original discussion regarding reverse string lookup is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba

Comment: One more quick thing. It's giving me C:\person\microsoft\ygkyg\mmddyy\ but I dont need the last "\"

Comment: Slightly simplified: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","?",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))` (note that this includes the trailing backslash)

Comment: =MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))),LEN(A1))))    I took out the +1 and it took out the last "/" from the path. Thanks

Comment: To get the grandparent path using the shorter solution `=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","?",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))`, we need to understand it. It translates to "Count the number of backslashes in the path (LEN of path - LEN of path without backslashes), and replace the final one with a '?'. Then take all characters to the left of that '?'."
So to get the grandparent path, you would replace the next earlier backslash, instead -- i.e. change `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))` to `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))-1`.

Answer (score 2):

For those coming to this problem in 2024, there's a much easier method available in Excel 2019/365 onward:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"\",-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on bendataclear's solution for Excel 2019/365, but if you don't have the file path in cell A1, you can use this formula:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(CELL("filename"),"\",-1)
```