# Excel Formula to get text between last two commas

Tags: excel

I have this data in cell A1:

```
Majestic Properties Design District, LLC, Ste. 101, 35 NE 40TH ST, Miami, FL 33137
```

There are a few other cells with these format address too, e.g.

```
Fortune International Realty Iriondo Ecker & Assoc. Inc., Ste 25, 260 Crandon Blvd, Key Biscayne, FL 33149
```

The output I want is

```
Miami
Key Biscayne
```

and so on

To get the Zip and State I did

```
=RIGHT(A1,8)
```

However now I need to get the city (that is the text between two commas from the last).

I do not want to use TEXT to COLUMN or any VBA. I would like to use a formula.

Comment: Not a programming question. Should be asked at Super User instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-10),1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))-1))+1,"")
```

Comment: +1 Nice, but this assumes that the length of the string from the last comma to the end is *always* equal to 10. If it isn't (e.g. if even a space delimiter is missing `,FL 33149`), then this formula will fail.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes, I'm assuming the string ends with comma followed by a space and then an 8 digit zip code. If there is variation he would need to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

This formula should also work, doesn't rely on the length of the zip code....

`=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",100)),200),100))`

Comment: +1: Nice trick. You are relying on LEN([Zip]&[State])<=100 but I guess that's fair enough :)

Comment: Amended condition: LEN([State Zip]&[Town/City])<=100

Comment: True enough.....you can always use LEN(A1) and LEN(A1)*2 in place of 100 and 200.....

Answer (score 2):

You ask how to extract the text sandwiched between the first and second rightmost commas in a cell.

Counting instances of a character starting from the *left* of a cell is easy. However, counting starting from the *right* is notoriously difficult in Excel. The higher you count, the more difficult: In general, the length of the worksheet formula you need to type if you want to find the `n`th instance of a character grows exponentially as something like `4^n`! (If you want to do this in one single formula.)

You may want to have a look at these earlier answers of mine to similar questions.

- [How to extract the last substring from a Excel column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135343/119775)
- [Excel - get file path from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505006/119775)

These answers show how to determine the position of the *first* instance of a character from the right (and then extract the entire text to the left or right of that). You need to locate not only the first but also the *second* instance of `,` (`n=2`) so your formula will be 16 times longer than the formula in those answers. Again, this is *if* you want to do it in one single formula.

If having an extra cell containing intermediate results is acceptable, then you can do this:

In cell A6: your address text

In cell A7, we remove the first comma from the right and all the text after that:

```
=LEFT(A6,FIND(CHAR(1),
 SUBSTITUTE(A6,$A$3,CHAR(1),LEN(A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A6,$A$3,""))))-1)
```

In cell A8, we keep only the text after the next rightmost comma:

```
=TRIM(MID(A7,FIND(CHAR(1),
 SUBSTITUTE(A7,$A$3,CHAR(1),LEN(A7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A7,$A$3,""))))+1,LEN(A7)))
```

Note that I store the `,` delimiter in cell `A3`, so it's easy to change.

Done. The result looks like this:

[image]

If you must have only 1 formula and no cell with intermediate results, then in the fomula of cell `A8`, replace every instance of `A7` with `LEFT(A6,FIND(CHAR(1),      SUBSTITUTE(A6,$A$3,CHAR(1),LEN(A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A6,$A$3,""))))-1)`. I forget what the limit is on the length of formulas in Excel...