# Get names from email column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column made up of emails. MOst of these are in the following format:

```
name.surname@domain.com
```

Is there any way I can extract the 'name' and populate column 2, and extract 'surname' and populate column 3 using an excel formula?

So the columns would read:

```
name.surname@domain.com       name         surname
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: [This existing question][1] shows how to break out substrings in Excel.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133287/how-to-extract-the-last-substring-from-a-excel-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Left and Mid functions to get columns 2 and 3, respectively. I will write out the formula for you in a minute...

Column 2:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)
```

Column 3:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1, FIND("@",A1)-FIND(".",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Name: `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)-1)`

Surname: `=MID(A1, SEARCH(".",A1)+1,SEARCH("@",A1)-SEARCH(".",A1)-1)`

Comment: Damn, beat me to it ;)
Except mine used FIND. Now I have to go read up on the difference between FIND and SEARCH ;)  Edit: Found it -> Case sensitivity.

Comment: FIND is case-sensitive, SEARCH isn't, so for punctuation searches it makes no difference which you use.....

Comment: Must have been a photo finish! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Surname can be extracted with this version

`=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1),1,FIND(".",A1),"")`

Answer (score 1):

Considering the format is firstname.lastname@domain.com, the first row is your header row and you need the first and last name in proper format, here's the formula

#### First Name

```
=PROPER(MID(A2,1,FIND(".",A2)-1))
```

#### Last Name

```
=PROPER(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,FIND("@",A2)-FIND(".",A2)-1))
```

Assuming your email id is in A2 and the First Name and Last Name needs to be extracted in B2 and C2 respectively