# Extracting text string after nth occurrence of a character in Excel (functions or VB)

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for VB or Excel function to return

`azat-tab-25mg`

from

`Y:\master-documentation\azat\dp\tab\25mg\2-drug-product\azat-tab-25mg-dp-1-bmi-[d-6475703-01-11].pdf`

Is there a function to get the text after the 7th occurrence of `\`?

Comment: Are you just looking to extract the filename i.e. everything after the *last* backslash? (i.e. not necessarily the 7th) If so, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5505006/119775) does this. And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133287/how-to-extract-the-last-substring-from-a-excel-column/6135343#6135343).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get parent folder path from file path using cell formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504797/get-parent-folder-path-from-file-path-using-cell-formula)

Answer (score 7):

The split function splits a string into an array of whatever size is required.
The first argument for Split is the text to split and the second is the delimiter.

```
Sub test()
Dim strFound As String
Text = "Y:\master-documentation\azat\dp\tab\25mg\2-drug-product\azat-tab-25mg-dp-1-bmi-[d-6475703-01-11].pdf"
strFound = Split(Text, "\")(7)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have data in cell A1 the following worksheet formula extracts everything after the 7th "\"

`=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","^^",7)),"")`

`SUBSTITUTE` function replaces the 7th `"\"` with `"^^"` [use any character or combination of characters that you know won't appear in the data]

...then `FIND` function finds the position of `"^^"` and allows `REPLACE` function to replace those characters and all before with nothing.

Comment: +1 Instead of `^^`, I suggest you use `?` (illegal in paths therefore certain it won't be there) or some non-printable character like `CHAR(1)`.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbett Yes, I knew "?" was illegal in filenames - wasn't sure about paths - that would be a good option here

Comment: still you're only half way there with your answer as the OP wants to return only a part of the *`azat-tab-25mg-dp-1-bmi....`*. Also I think this just adds extra overhead

Comment: @vba4all Agreed.....but he does say `"is there a mid function to get the text after the 7th occurance of \ ?"` - and the way to limit the text after that isn't defined, I assumed Gary knew how to do that already.

Comment: Old thread, hopefully you are still active. How would you reverse the polarity on this formula to return all the text *before* the nth instance of a character? Edit: nvm "=SUBSTITUTE(E2,REPLACE(E2,1,FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(E2,"/","^^",2)),""),"")"... elementary.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = Right(fullfilepath, Len(fullfilepath) - InStrRev(fullfilepath, "\"))
```

`InStrRev` finds the first occurrance of a string starting the search from the end.

Answer (score 1):

To return

> azat-tab-25mg

from your original string, I returned everything from the **last** "\" up to the **third** "-" following.

Worksheet Excel function:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),
"-",CHAR(1),3),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(
A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"-",CHAR(1),3))-1)
```

User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function Meds(S As String) As String
    Dim S1 As Variant, S2 As Variant

S1 = Split(S, "\")
S2 = Split(S1(UBound(S1)), "-")
ReDim Preserve S2(0 To 2)
Meds = Join(S2, "-")

End Function
```