# Find and delete text within a cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have pasted text in cell A1 that may look like this:

"Vanguard - Total Market - Composite" or "Vanguard - Total Market - Commingled"

I want to cut off the " - Composite" or " - Commingled" and return the rest in cell B1. Currently I'm using this formula in B1:

=LEFT(A1,FIND(" - Composite",A1)-1)

However, I can't figure out how to look for multiple terms (i.e. Composite or Commingled). Is there a formula that could accomplish this? If not, how could I do it in VBA?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Will your data always have two `-`?

Comment: Are they always in the form of `Company - Index - Method`?

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - Composite", ""), " - Commingled", "")` ?

Comment: @assylias That works perfect and so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTITUTE` function [and chain multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644497/find-and-delete-text-within-a-cell-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment66592515_39644497):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - Composite", ""), " - Commingled", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're simply looking to strip everything past the second occurrence of `-`, i.e. returning the trimmed (extra whitespace removed) text left of the first `-` character. Adapting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135343/1188513) to locate the last word in the string, this would be it:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,LEN(A1)))),"-","",2))
```

This formula will work with or without the spaces around the `-`, and regardless of what follows:

[image: formula in action]

---

If even spacing is important, you can wrap it with `SUBSTITUTE` functions:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,LEN(A1)))),"-","",2)),"-"," - "),"  "," ")
```

And now you have clean, identically-formatted output for all cases:

[image: even spacing]

Answer (score 1):

I've made this formula that will work with many possibilities as long you fill the possibilities range, not needing to change the formula when there's a new one. Here it is:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Possibilities,A2)))*ROW(Possibilities)),SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Possibilities,A2)))*COLUMN(Possibilities)))),A2)-1)
```

[image]