# Nesting Excel formulas to extract e-mail address top-level domain

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract the top-level domain from e-mail addresses using Excel formulas.

I tried it first with concatenating RIGHT(..) Formulas and splitting for the dot. Sadly I do not know how to do this recursively with excel formulas, so I swapped to deleting all characters except the last 4. Now the problem is, when I split my formulas into single cells it works perfectly fine. If I try to use them together, I get only the output of the first inner Formula. How do I fix this?

```
=RIGHT(B8; LEN(B8)-(LEN(B8)-4))
=RIGHT(BF8;LEN(BF8)-FIND(".";BF8))
```

These are the formulas split into single cells. And here both together

```
=RIGHT(RIGHT(B8; LEN(B8)-(LEN(B8)-4));LEN(B8)-FIND(".";B8))
```

I get the same return value as in the first row from this formula

```
=RIGHT(B8; LEN(B8)-(LEN(B8)-4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `=RIGHT(B8; LEN(B8)-(LEN(B8)-4))` is just a uselessly complicated version of `=RIGHT(B8; 4)`.

Substituting this for BF8 in

```
=RIGHT(BF8;LEN(BF8)-FIND(".";BF8))
```

yields this

```
=RIGHT(RIGHT(B8; 4);LEN(RIGHT(B8; 4))-FIND(".";RIGHT(B8; 4)))
```

which can be simplified as

```
=RIGHT(RIGHT(B8; 4);4-FIND(".";RIGHT(B8; 4)))
```

So that's the answer to your question.

But note that **this will fail when parsing e-mail addresses whose top-level domain name has more than 3 characters**! So it won't work for e.g. `test@test.info`. Note that top-level domains can be [up to 63 characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239264/119775)!

In [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135343/119775), I give a more general solution to this problem, not limited to searching a predetermined number of characters from the right.

```
=MID(B8;FIND(CHAR(1);SUBSTITUTE(B8;".";CHAR(1);LEN(B8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B8;".";""))))+1;LEN(B8))
```

returns everything after the last `.` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Dot character may appear in left part if e-mail, like: john.johnson@email.com
So, you can't just find "." you need firstly find @, then find dot in right substring.
Tehese are your steps:

```
1. =FIND("@"; B8)
find @ character place

2. =RIGHT(B8;LEN(B8) - FIND("@"; B8))
get substring right from @

3. =FIND(".";RIGHT(B8;LEN(B8) - FIND("@"; B8)))
find "." in step 2 substring

4. =RIGHT(RIGHT(B8;LEN(B8) - FIND("@"; B8)); LEN(RIGHT(B8;LEN(B8) - FIND("@"; B8))) - FIND(".";RIGHT(B8;LEN(B8) - FIND("@"; B8))))
get right(step2; len(step2) - step3)
```

Comment: "*Dot character may appear in left part if e-mail*" That's why OP was only searching only the last 4 characters.

Comment: That's why my solution is more common - for any domain length.