# Formula for sequential numbering based on rules

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have a very complex Excel formula that I need to create, but I keep getting stuck. I have data that looks like this:

```
Date         ID   Focal  Time      Condition
08/22/2014   FJ   1      7:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   1      7:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   1      7:52:00   T
08/22/2014   RJ   1      8:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   2      9:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   2      9:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   2      9:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   2      9:52:00   T
08/22/2014   FJ   3      10:52:00  T
08/22/2014   FJ   3      10:52:00  T
08/22/2014   FJ   1      11:32:00  C
08/22/2014   FJ   1      11:32:00  C
08/22/2014   RJ   2      11:52:00  T
08/22/2014   RJ   2      11:52:00  T
08/22/2014   FJ   4      10:52:00  T
08/22/2014   FJ   4      10:52:00  T
08/22/2014   MD   1      12:52:00  T
08/22/2014   RJ   3      13:52:00  T
08/22/2014   RJ   3      13:52:00  T 
08/22/2014   FJ   2      14:52:00  C 
08/23/2014   FJ   1      7:52:00   T
08/23/2014   FJ   1      7:52:00   T
08/23/2014   RJ   1      8:52:00   T
08/23/2014   FJ   1      9:52:00   C
```

I need the Focal number column to autopopulate according to the following rules:

- The first entry will always be "1".
- Each ID should have the same Focal number when their Date, Time, and Condition are the same.
- When only the time changes, the number should be sequentially listed.
- When the condition changes, the number should start over at 1, and then these should be sequential when the time changes.
- If the condition changes to an ID that has previously experienced it, the sequential number should pick up when it left off.
- Also, when the ID changes, the number should start over at one.
- Finally, a new date will start this process for all IDs all over again.

Comment: I doubt you will get a formula to do this.  Have you considered VBA?

Comment: @mermaid-niki Why is the last row's Focal 2, not 1? New date starts over again, condition change starts over at 1... This is the first C for FJ on 08/23...

Comment: @chrisneilsen: [Famous last words](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5504797/119775)

Comment: Sorry - the last one should be a "1".  (Just fixed that) --- I consider my problem solved. You are all amazing. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution as an array formula (enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) e.g. in C2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A2,$B$1:$B1,$B2,$E$1:$E1,$E2)=0,1,MAX(IF(($A$1:$A1=$A2)*($B$1:$B1=$B2)*($E$1:$E1=$E2),$C$1:$C1,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A2,$B$1:$B1,$B2,$E$1:$E1,$E2,$D$1:$D1,$D2)>0,0,1)))
```

- This is looking at all the rows above the current one (e.g. `$A$1:$A1` locks the start as the top and the end as the row above)
- If there is now matching date, ID & condition in the rows above --> 1
- Otherwise, use the array formula part to find the `MAX` Focal for that date/ID/condition and, if it is a new time, add 1

Hope this is a clear enough explanation...

It seems to give two differences to your example... The final row (as per my comment) and also FJ/T/10:%2 with Focal 4... that combination already exists.

Good luck, and remember to enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution, I was a bit too quick to dismiss a single formula as being too complicated!

Comment: Nicest Excel answer I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have something, but I haven't been able to do it as a single formula. Enter the following in row 2 and copy the formula down:

In column F:

```
=A2&B2&D2&E2    ' Concatenate the required fields to create a reference
```

In Column G:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)>1,"",1)    ' Create a marker to determine the first occurrence of each reference
```

In column H:

```
=IF(G2=1,A2&B2&E2,"")    ' Create a reference to count occurrences in a day
```

In column I:

```
=IF(G2=1,COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2),0)    ' Count first occurrences in the day
```

In column J:

```
=INDEX($I$2:I2,MATCH(F2,$F$2:F2,0))    ' Return the count of first occurrences
```

It can be tidied up quite a bit but I think it does what you are asking for and this was the simplest way to show what I did.