# VBA/Formula, Parse Parent of of Path

Tags: vba, excel

I was not able to get the answers from [Get parent folder path from file path using cell formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504797/get-parent-folder-path-from-file-path-using-cell-formula)  to work with my data.

Using the below, only one part of my path gets trimmed.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","?",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

I have /stack/over/flow/today/is/friday in A1, above formulas will give me /stack/over/flow/today/is/

Result i want is /stack or stack/ or just stack from my path.

Any VBA,functions or formulas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the first text between the first 2 "/"

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),998,999))
```

[image]

Comment: @Jonnyboi there is a check mark by the answer that will mark this as the correct answer, it is something only you can do.  Please click it.  Also I noticed that none of your questions had correct answers marked you probably should go back and fix that.

Answer (score 2):

UDF ( User Defined Function)
you can use the function as follow while your path is in A1.

=GetFirstFolder(A1, "/", 1) will return: Stack

```
Function GetFirstFolder(sPath As String, sDiv As String, Optional lOrder As Long = 0) As String
        Application.Volatile 'This will make your function recalculate wherever the function is put.

        GetFirstFolder = Split(sPath, sDiv)(lOrder)
End Function
```

Hope this helps.
hadi

Answer (score 1):

And a slightly different approach with a shorter formula:

```
=MID(A1,2,FIND("/",A1,2)-2)
```

The `2` for `start` skips over the first `/`

The `-2` in the length results in not returning the second `/`