# Isolate string from filepath in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have 4 rows in Column A (titled filepaths) with the following filepath content:

A1: /page1/page2/page3

A2: /page4/page5

A3: /page6/page7/page8/page9

A4: /page10

...I need a formula to isolate the parent of the last child into eg the corresponding column B (titled parent), so:

B1 would derive a value of page2

B2 would derive a value of page4

B3 would derive a value of page8

B4 would derive a value of [blank] as it has no parent

Can anyone suggest a formula please that could achieve this?

Thanks

I tried:

`=IF(LEN(A1) = LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")),"",MID(A1,FIND(REPT("/",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1),LEN(A1)))`
and

`=LET(v,A1,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(v,"/"),LEN(v)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(v,"/",""))))`

and

[Get parent folder path from file path using cell formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504797/get-parent-folder-path-from-file-path-using-cell-formula) (came close isolating entire filepath above child)

but can't isolate the parent.

Answer (score 4):

For a single cell try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=@TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,-2)
```

For the whole range:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTAFTER("/"&TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4,"/",-1),"/",-1)
```

---

For older versions of Excel, I'd like to link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) Q&A about the use of `FILTERXML()` instead of a mixture of `MID()`, `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` etc..

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]"),"")
```

If you are on an Excel version prior to 2013 and/or on Mac, then I think you'd rather be a little bit more dynamic then your own answer:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*2),LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: All formulas are linked now. this is really helpful =)

Comment: Is the `@` in your TAKE/TEXTSPLIT solution to cope with if the TEXTSPLIT would spill 2D?

Comment: @P.b Yes that's correct.

Comment: Oh I see what it does. It spills the last 2 column results without it. Adding @shows only the first of the 2. Very clever and clean solution.

Comment: @P.b, it's called implicit intersection. Adding the '@' will return the top-left element of an array. It's either that or a more verbose `TAKE()`.

Comment: I know it works that way, but I am used to seeing that being used in ranges, so it returns the first. Basically it does exactly that, but in another context.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer `=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",100)),200),100))` if it helps others. Works in Excel 2019 for Mac. Some solutions depend on the Excel version it appears.