# Excel formula (not VBA) to calculate basename of a file path?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to determine the basename, i.e. the last path component of a file path in Excel without defining a custom VBA function?

For example, if cell `A1` has the value

```
C:\Some\deep\directory\structure\file.txt
```

the formula in `B1` should use `A1` to return

```
file.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you opposed to using VBA? There are much more reliable methods of doing this than simply stripping out what you will be assuming is the path separator.

Comment: Actually (almnost) duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba

Comment: @CodyGray: I believe a formula is faster; also I like the workbook VBA free so there is no user interaction (activating macros) necessary.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately, in a scenario where you have VBA functions called from a sheet, and a macro is executing, changing values on the sheet and causing the formulas to recalculate, *particularly in a loop,* Excel enters some sort of a gray area. Functions may execute properly, or they may return an error (e.g. `#VALUE`) for no reason at all (not reproducible when slowly stepping through code!); execution flow can stop unexpectedly in the middle of a routine; or Excel may crash with an invalid operation performed. I'm so fed up with that that I now avoid VBA on sheets as much as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

Comment: I notice that this doesn't work if there's a space in the file path.  It's because of using spaces as the outer substitute char, but then finding spaces earlier in the string.

Comment: Replaces the spaces with something else: "!" for example.

Comment: I'm not sure at what point you're suggesting the replacement. I thought you (and @Karsten) might want to know about this shortfall in the solution.  If a replacement char is used it should and illegal file name char like: ? : < > |

Comment: @Dougglancy I have amended accordingly.

Comment: aaaand for Linux paths:
`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))`

Comment: it works in google docs as well as of 2021-01

Answer (score 6):

To get everything after the last backslash try this formula

`=REPLACE(A1,1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND("\",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),"")`

Comment: +1 I don't know if I'll ever remember this pattern.  If not, I'll at least be filled with the same childlike wonder each time I see it.

Comment: Beautiful. A critical part of converting HTML-link local paths for each user's filespace (ie, opening a spreadsheet looking for different local paths on each computer). Thanks.