# How can I parse a column by a number of characters?

Tags: excel

I want to pull the last two text terms that are found on either side of the last period but I'm not sure how to parse this out of my excel sheet easily.  If I can find a formula to find everything Right of the 2nd period from the right that would be great --- But I haven't come across any way to do this yet.  If someone with more experience in Excel could help I would greatly appreciate it!

- Examples of what I have: (x 20000 records)

104.526.737.me.com

102.sub-62649-42.httm.com

26.4.326.sub-ip-static.something.net

- I was to get from that: (for all of the records)

me.com

httm.com

something.net

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer for [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba), I modified the formula to replace periods instead of spaces, and adding **-1** on the second line.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","|",
 LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")) - 1)))
```

Just copy and paste for each row you need.