# Delete Certain Characters in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have ~4000 records of data in Excel 2010 that as below:

```
QW3-WE-2232-322-A-2
WETE-33-3REE-33-WEWE-3
DEE-3YED-3432-DXSDDD-3FESE-2
343-34SE-34323-AWBE-3
ABDC-343-3THYT-2
```

I want the data to look like this where everything after the last dash is deleted.

```
QW3-WE-2232-322-A
WETE-33-3REE-33-WEWE
DEE-3YED-3432-DXSDDD-3FESE
343-34SE-34323-AWBE
ABDC-343-3THYT
```

Was wondering if there was an easy way to do this Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Answering the original question where at most two "-" separators occur:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-1)
```

Answering the modified question where an arbitrary number of "-" separators occur:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))-1)
```

This answer is via [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba), where several adaptable options may be found as well.

This is very clever, but with a little VBA a more straightforward answer could be devised. The VBA to do this can be very simple, but I recommend bringing in Regular Expressions for more flexible solution you can use on other similar problems.

```
Function RegExReplace(pattern As String, sourceString As String, replaceVar As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RE.pattern = pattern
    RE.Global = True
    RegExReplace = RE.Replace(sourceString, replaceVar)
End Function
```

Then in your worksheet you would use

```
=RegExReplace("-[^-]*$",A1,"")
```

Comment: Looks good but the data differs in size all through the records.Sorry I didn't specify that in the beginning

Comment: Modified question is now analogous to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just want to get rid if the last two characters at the end of the string.  If so then you could try `=Left(A1,Len(A1)-2)`