# Excel VBA Regular Expression to Remove Leading Number, Period, and Space?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a sheet that I use an Excel VBA macro to automatically fill all worksheet page headers (NOT column headers) with relevant information on a button click.  This macro uses wSheet.Name to populate the header title.  However, wSheet.Name often contains leading numbers, periods, and spaces that I don't want to appear in the header.

Note the following sample worksheet names:

```
Cover Page
1a. Test Page
1b. Sample Page
2. Another Test Page
3. Yet Another Test Page
4. Almost the Last Example Page
998.  Last Example Page
```

I would like to remove these leading numbers, periods, and spaces using a regular expression, yet I'm unsure how to code it using VBA in Excel.  I would like it to be as flexible as possible.  Here is an example of how I would like the worksheet names to appear:

```
Cover Page
Test Page
Sample Page
Another Test Page
Yet Another Test Page
Almost the Last Example Page
Last Example Page
```

Here is my existing code that populates the headers:

```
Sub FillHeaders()
'
' Auto_Fill_Project_Name Macro
'
For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> "Cover Page" Then
        wSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = _
            "&16&KFF0000" & ActiveSheet.Range("J1") & "&10&K000000 &16" & " " & _
            wSheet.Name & Chr(13) & "&10 &11 Revision Date: "
    End If
    Next wSheet
'
End Sub
```

How can I modify this to accomplish my goal?

Thank you!

EDIT -- I have taken the following approach:

```
Function remleaddig(str As String)
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = "^\S*\."
    str = regEx.Replace(str, "")
    remleaddig = Trim(str)
End Function
```

Comment: `^\d+\w\.\s` matches `1.b Another Test Title`? Unless that's not a type `^\S*\. ` was still able to match all your examples. Are you sure it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: -- Added `UDF`**

```
Function StripChars(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With objRegex
 .Pattern = "^.+\.\s+"
.ignorecase = True
StripChars = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

**Initial Post`**

I would combine the [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) with a variant array to reduce code runtime. The code below uses

1. Late bindging to set up the `regexp`
2. The values in column A of the `ActiveSheet` are read into a variable array `X` (Note that the code will handle a 2D range, ie you could use `X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2` to work on column A and B
3. The `regexp` strips out the unwanted characters - it will handle more than one space if it is presnt before the text you want to retain
4. The cleaned text is dumped to the active sheet starting in `C1`. Change this line to move the dump - you could make it dump back over the orginal values starting in `A1`. `[c1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X`

[image]

**Code**

```
Sub QuickUpdate()
Dim X()
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long

X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With objRegex
 .Pattern = "^.+\.\s+"
.ignorecase = True
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
X(lngRow, lngCol) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), vbNullString)
Next lngCol
Next lngRow
End With

[c1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)).Value2 = X

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can actually use regular expressions via the RegEx object of VBScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041710/1756702 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on my comment.

This required a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` (or whatever the number is on your machine)

```
Dim r As RegExp
Set r = New RegExp
r.Pattern = "^\S*\. "

Dim c As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A7")   ' <-- Set this to your range
For Each c In rng
    c.Value = r.Replace(c.Value, "")
Next c
```

If all that text is in one cell then change it to

```
Dim r As RegExp
Set r = New RegExp
r.Pattern = "^\S*\. "
r.MultiLine = True
r.Global = True

Dim c As Range
Set c = Range("J1")
    c.Value = r.Replace(c.Value, "") '<--or place the result where ever you want
```

The regex explained

- `"^`     This says that the pattern specified must start at the beginning of the string. we don't want to match numbers that exist in the middle of your header title.
- `\S`     This matches everything except white space ([^a-zA-Z0-9]). i.e. it will match letters and numbers.
- `*`      This matches 0 or more of the previous pattern
- `\.`     This matches a period (period must be escaped with a `\` because the `.` itself means it wants to match 1 or more of the previous pattern.
- `"`     This matches a single space.

Comment: Thank you Brad.  I'm trying to understand this.  First, the variable is initialized as a new regular expression with a pattern matching one or more numbers, a decimal point, then a space?  Next, a new range is initialized and given a range of cells.  Then this code loops through each cell in the range and replaces the value with a new value. What cells are we trying to replace though, as I am trying to fill a page header, not just a column header? I'm confused. I assume I could use this regex to create a new substring based off of wSheet.Name?

Comment: Does all of that live in the cell `J1`? and you are just grabbing it from there to put in the header?

Comment: I apologize, that J1 cell was irrelevant to my question and I phrased the question vaguely.  Please see the edit I made to my original post.  I almost have it working, the regex pattern needs some modification, though.