# Excel: How to extract the text between the last set of square brackets in a cell

Tags: excel, timestamp, text-extraction

I have a cell of text which has multiple timestamps in it surrounded by square brackets.

```
[ANon-02/05/2013 08:32:30 - 0:15 mins]
```

Update here

```
[JBloggs-07/05/2013 09:30:13 - 0:15 mins]
```

Update here

```
[JBloggs-09/05/2013 16:02:19 - 0:15 mins]
```

Update here

```
[ANon-10/05/2013 10:42:41 - 1:0 mins]
```

I would like to be able to extract just the last timestamp, i.e.

```
[ANon-10/05/2013 10:42:41 - 1:0 mins]
```

I can extract the first set of timestamps using the following, but I cannot work out how to edit the formula to give me the last timestamp.

```
=MID(I3,SEARCH("[",I3)+1,SEARCH("]",I3)-SEARCH("[",I3)+1)
```

I would by grateful if someone could assist.

Comment: you mean that after update #3 you have a concatenation of your 4 timestamps in one single cell?

Answer (score 0):

as a modification to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba) I'd propose to use

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[","|",LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[","")))),999)
```

or - if you also want to remove the enclosing brackets

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[","|",LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[","")))),999),"[",""),"]","")
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the sample data you could also use

```
="["&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[",REPT(" ",500)),500))
```