# Excel - How to grab individual components of a address

Tags: excel

I have a big list with full addresses in excel. Each address has a single cell. I am having trouble creating a formula to grab the street name to put in another cell and grabbing the city to put in a different cell.

Here is example cases of what my data looks like

```
12 Apple RD Harwich, MA 11111
1213 Strawberry Crossing Loop Tampa, FL 22222
123 Pear Dr. Colorado Springs, CO 33333
12345 RIVERSIDE DR Lowertown, PA 44444
6232 N Rockstar ST Philadelphia, PA 44444
123 TOWN ST Plympton, MA 55555
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate address elements from 1 cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915075/separate-address-elements-from-1-cell-in-excel)

Comment: This will actually be extremely difficult since excel doesn't know when the street name stops and when the city name starts.

Comment: You'll need to construct a table of possible city names, and use some logic to ensure that overlap is accounted for (eg. one name part of another).  Once you've done that, you can separate the rest easily.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a quick and easy way to solve your problem but here is a way to do the required work efficiently and fast - probably more so than if you spend time on getting code that will, at best, only produce a result that needs to be reviewed.

In a nutshell, the code offered here will create a textbox for each cell as you click on it. It's a textbox because it offers capabilities a cell doesn't have. In the text box you enter a single comma, to separate street address from city, and press enter. The split is done on the spot, is immediately editable, and the textbox moves to the next line.

The code can handle more commas. And it can handle each part individually. I have demonstrated this on the state and ZIP code part. There is a note in the code where you can remove this extra. The code also adds the comma (and any other changes made at that time) to the original data. There is another note in the code where you can remove a line to keep the original data untouched.

The code is a little elaborate and, at the same time, rough around the edges because it was adapted from another project. As it is now in consists of 2 parts. The first part contains event procedures which call other procedures in the other part. The latter also contains supporting functions for itself. The first part must be installed in the code module of the worksheet on which you want the action. That is the worksheet with the original addresses in them. You can install this same code behind several worksheets in the same workbook. Here is part 1.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 069

    Const StopAction As Boolean = False      ' change to TRUE to stop
    Const SourceClm  As Long = 1            ' column containing the data
    
    If StopAction Or Target.Column <> SourceClm Then
        KillTbx Target
    Else
        SetTbx Target.Cells(1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Splitter_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                           ByVal Shift As Integer)
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020
    KeyCode = KeyUpEvent(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

Please observe the two constants at the top. You can set them to suit your needs. `StopAction`, if TRUE will disable the creation of text boxes, in fact returning your worksheet to its original behaviour. `SourceClm` specifies the column in which you have your original data. In my trials that was column A, identified by its number, 1. If you have several installations in the same workbook these settings can be individually different.

The code below goes into a standard code module. That is a module you have to insert. By default VBA will name it `Module1`. I recommend to rename it suitably. I named mine *STO_62962096* which will help me find this thread again if ever needed.

```
Option Explicit
    
Private Const MagName   As String = "Splitter"

Sub SetTbx(Target As Range)
    ' 069
    
    Dim Tbx         As OLEObject            ' the TextBox being created
    Dim BackColor   As Long                 ' background color
    Dim FontColor   As Long                 ' font color
    
    BackColor = 16777152                    ' = sky blue
    FontColor = vbBlack                     ' = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Tbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If Err Then
        Set Tbx = Target.Worksheet.OLEObjects _
                        .Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", _
                             Link:=False, _
                             DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                             Left:=100, Top:=100, _
                             Width:=100, Height:=20)
    End If
    
    With Tbx
        With .Object
            .BackColor = BackColor
            .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
            .IntegralHeight = False
            .ForeColor = FontColor
            .Font.Size = Target.Font.Size
            .Text = Target.Value
        End With
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width
        .Height = (Target.Offset(1).Top - .Top)
        .Name = MagName
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub

Sub KillTbx(Target As Range)
    ' 069

    Dim Tbx             As OLEObject        ' TextBox
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Tbx = Target.Worksheet.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If Err = 0 Then Tbx.Delete
    Err.Clear
    Target.Select
End Sub

Function KeyUpEvent(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, _
                    ByVal Shift As Integer) As Integer
    ' 069

    Dim Tbx         As OLEObject
    Dim n           As Long                 ' offset
    
    Set Tbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then                    ' Enter
        With Tbx
            SplitAddress .Object.Text, .TopLeftCell.Row
            ' remove the next line to KEEP original data
            .TopLeftCell.Value = .Object.Text
            KeyCode = 40                    ' move to next row
        End With
    End If
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38, 40                         ' Up-arrow / Down-arrow
            n = IIf(KeyCode = 38, -1, 1)
            Tbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(n).Select
            Tbx.Object.Text = ActiveCell.Value
        Case 9                              ' tab: move right/left
            n = IIf(Shift, -1, 1)
            Tbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(, n).Select
            Tbx.Object.Text = ActiveCell.Value
    End Select
    
    KeyUpEvent = KeyCode
End Function

Private Sub SplitAddress(ByVal Txt As String, _
                         ByVal Rt As Long)
    ' 069
    
    Const TgtClm    As Long = 4             ' first target column (change to suit)
    Const StateClm  As Long = 7             ' State followed by ZIP (change to suit)
    
    Dim Sp()        As String               ' address array
    Dim Ct          As Long                 ' target column
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' output array
    
    If Len(Txt) Then
        ReDim Arr(1 To StateClm - TgtClm + 2)
        Sp = Split(Txt, ",")
        For Ct = 0 To UBound(Sp)
            Arr(Ct + 1) = Trim(Sp(Ct))
        Next Ct
        
        ' remove the next block of 5 lines to NOT separate state & ZIP
        Sp = Split(Trim(Replace(Sp(Ct - 1), "  ", " ")))
        Arr(Ct) = ""
        For Ct = 0 To UBound(Sp)
            Arr(Ct + StateClm - TgtClm + 1) = Trim(Sp(Ct))
        Next Ct
        
        Cells(Rt, TgtClm).Resize(, UBound(Arr)).Value = Arr
        Columns(TgtClm).Resize(, StateClm - TgtClm + 2).AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

Look for the procedure *SplitAddress* and adjust the two constants you find there. The code splits the address into a, theoretically, unlimited number of parts. The first of these will be written to the column named *TgtClm*, 4 in the above code, which identifies column D. The State/ZIP combination has its own similar design and therefore its own first column (the first of 2 in this case). If you don't use this feature (you can disable it in this same procedure) set the constant *StateClm* to a number at least equal to the maximum number of splits you expect.

Note that the code creates an array with `StateClm - TgtClm + 2` elements. If you only want 3 columns, as per your question, StateClm - TgtClm + 2 must be => 3. To the right of the result the code will over-write existing data for as many columns as this formula specifies.