# Get the Last String value of n length after a delimiter from string using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the last split value from the cell.

The input cell C1 value = main\java\com\tms\vsc\ppo\data\domain\Ppo.java

which must be copied to another cell B1
Expected output in B1 is 
Ppo.java

Below is the formula tried over in cell B1

```
=RIGHT(RIGHT(C1,FIND("\",C1)),256)
```

and

```
=RIGHT(C1,FIND("\",C1))
```

Can anyone help me out. Its a pure excel and not VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

Note that you must guarantee that your cell does not contain the character `|`

This is extracted from here:
[How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba)

Comment: Cell doesn't contain the | character