# How to get last word in a cell using Excel Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to get the last word in a cell however, it does not seem to be appearing getting the last word of the cell.  It seems to get the partial match and not working correctly. I am using `=IFERROR(RIGHT(AP2,SEARCH(" ",AP2)-1),AP2)`.  This works great for getting the first word in a cell even where the first word is the only word in a cell.  Any ideas on why this is not getting the last word correctly? [image]

Comment: I this you can find answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba)

Comment: Do you really want to get the last word? From AP11 that would mean the result is "Brom" (not "West Brom"). If you want the away team try this formula. `=IFERROR(REPLACE(AP2,1,SEARCH(" v ",AP2)+2,""),"")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the below worked for me.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(AP40," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

I can only assume my other method is unreliable at getting the last word.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this UDF which can be used in another sub routine or on the worksheet as well.

```
Function GetLastWord(ByVal Str As String) As String
Dim arrStr
arrStr = Split(Str, " ")
GetLastWord = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))
End Function
```

If you need to use it on the worksheet, assuming your string is in A1 then try this...

```
=GetLastWord(A1)
```

Comment: You can use `InStrRev` to find the position of the last space rather than splitting into an array:  `GetLastWord = Mid(Str, InStrRev(Str, " ") + 1)`

Comment: Yes, you can. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is based on the first occurrence of a space in the string.

For example with "Man City V Stoke" in the formula SEARCH(" ",AP11) is looking for the first occurrence of a space which occurs at position 4. You are then subtracting 1 from this and using this as the number of characters to return from the right of the original string. So you get Right("Man City V Stoke",3) which is "oke".

A better way is a formula such as

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(AP11," ",REPT(" ",LEN(AP11))),LEN(AP11)))
```

[find text after last space](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/498759-find-text-after-last-space-string.html)
The part written: `=SUBSTITUTE(AP1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(AP1)))`

This inserts spaces the length of the string (16) in place of every occurrence of a space i.e.

```
Man                City                V                Stoke
```

When you then do RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(AP11," ",REPT(" ",LEN(AP11))),LEN(AP11))
you are guaranteed to only get whitespace followed by the last word. You then use TRIM to get rid of this white space.