# excel text to column delimiter starting from end of the row

Tags: excel, text-to-column

I have strings in a column that look like this

```
/name/safsdf/231232/asesa/filename.mp4
/ds2/sasdsfsdf/2fd32/a234sa/filenameb.mp4
...
...
```

so text to column works great i can easily make a column that has just the filenames without the folders.

My problem is its inconsistent.

so some rows have more or less than 5 / which screws up the column.
For example:

```
/name/safsdf/231232/asesa/filename.mp4
/ds2/sasdsfsdf/2fd32/a234sa/filenameb.mp4
/ds3/123/12321/123/123/filenamec.ts
...
```

will result in the last column being:

```
filename.mp4
filenameb.mp4
123
```

I'm looking for the result to be:

```
filename.mp4
filenameb.mp4
filenamec.ts
```

Is there a way to do text to colum in reverse where it starts looking for delimiters at the end of the row?
This will give me a list of proper filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an answer. Here is one more approach:

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

Comment: @chowpay It is cannibalized version of the formula explained here: http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/333-Get-Field-from-Delimited-Text-String?s=36b969a7a10fc3b2ef7d2b7dfefc7bab

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a reverse string search to grab everything to the right of the last "/".

The formula (assume one of your strings is in A1) would be

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A1)),A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))))
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/350390/4717755) and [this site](https://www.exceltactics.com/reverse-string-search-excel-using-find/2/) for an explanation of why this works.

Comment: ok wow that was way more complicated than I thought. Ended up doing this in python by the time you posted this. But it looks good so I'll mark it as the answer for someone who needs this in excel

Answer (score 1):

Take a copy and Replace `*/` with nothing.