# FIND in reverse (from right to left, FINDrev) function Excel UDF

Tags: excel, find, user-defined-functions, right-to-left, string-search

I spent a long time searching for a simple FIND-in-reverse function in Excel and found some formulas, which were way too long for my taste (e.g. [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba)).

So I ended up creating my own simpler one, below, which gives you the last word in a string by finding the position of the last space (or the 1st one from right to left).

```
=RIGHT(A1,FINDrev(” “,A1))
```

If you run this formula on the sentence above it (put in cell A1), it will give you the result "left)." All you need is to define a 3-row VBA UDF FINDrev() and save it in a permanently available xlam add-in:

```
Public Function FINDrev(Find_text As String, Within_text As String)
FINDrev = Len(Within_text)-Len(Find_text)-InStrRev(Within_text, Find_text)+1
End Function
```

Has anyone found a simpler solution for FIND-in-reverse?

Comment: There are definitely some options to do so, but a worksheet Instrrev would have been nice. Your function can be made a little simpler though, using MID and Instrrev

Comment: Btw, another alternative is using split

Answer (score 1):

You could try the VBA build-in function `InStrRev()`.

You can find document here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function .

I will make a UDF like this.

```vb
Function myRightRev(find_text As String, Within_text As String) As String
    myRightRev = Mid(Within_text, InStrRev(Within_text, find_text) + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, MID works if the find_text is just 1 character long (there is a small typo in your formula, should be "+ 1)" at the end.

If you look for something longer, e.g. "\\", the +1 at the end needs to be replaced with LEN(Find_text)

Comment: @Vasko Thanks.  It's my typo.