# Excel - parent-child from a list of values

Tags: excel, parent-child

I've a list a values (column-1) which contains multiple parents and childs levels and I need to associate in another column which is the parent of each cell.

Any ideas on how to do that easily in excel?
really thanks!

```
COLUMN-1            COLUMN-2
  **A   
  A.01**                **A**
  **A.01.01**           **A.01**
  A.01.01.01        **A.01.01**
  A.01.01.01.01     A.01.01.01
  A.01.01.01.02     A.01.01.01
  A.01.01.01.03     A.01.01.01
  A.01.01.01.04     A.01.01.01
  A.01.01.02        **A.01.01**
  A.01.01.02.01     A.01.01.02
  A.01.01.02.02     A.01.01.02
  A.01.01.02.03     A.01.01.02
  A.01.01.02.04     A.01.01.02
  A.01.01.03        **A.01.01**
  A.01.01.03.01     A.01.01.03
  A.01.01.03.02     A.01.01.03
  A.01.01.03.03     A.01.01.03
  A.01.01.03.04     A.01.01.03
```

FINAL GOAL

[image]

Comment: Include whatever it is you have tried.

Comment: Looks like you could simply remove the characters after the last period, which will be simple. If you have an example which contradicts this hypothesis, suggest you give it.

Comment: Hi Jos! I've cases like 1C.00.200.0010.a, in which I should cut only the ".a" part.

Answer (score 0):

Jos Woolley's approach looks likely.
For *how* to do it, see [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba) (adapating . for spaces)

Comment: Basically I should search for all the text part before the dot (searching from right) and than delete that part (that has no fixed number of characters) including the dot