Extract text having different length in excel
I have a list of address data as below. But they don't follow any pattern. Comma, dot or space was used to separate words. I applied the formula
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1))

but the result was not as expected. Unfortunately, the excel I'm using doesn't have TEXTAFTER.



Data
Result
Desired result




22, 29 CHIÊU LIÊU TĐH DĨ AN BD
DĨ AN BD
Dĩ An


22 ĐLTD KCN VS Thuận Giao Thuận An BD
Thuận An BD
Thuận An


22 ĐLTD KCN VS Thuận Giao Thuận An BD
uận An BD
Thuận An


22 Đ.ĐT743B THỐNG NHẤT 1 DA DĨ AN BD
1 DA DĨ AN BD
Dĩ An




Are you using a version of Excel that has Power Query included (2016 and later)? On Data tab > From Table/Range > Add Column > Columns from Example. Start typing in your desired results and see if Power Query can produce a rule.

Do all the strings end with " BD"?

I think there might be a solution to your problem under this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/350264/1328439. In your formula would work only if you could reverse the string before feeding it as an argument to FIND.

@cybernetic.nomad no, not all of them. I extract the text for further lookup

@DimaChubarov but I want to get the text after the third space from the right e.g. Dĩ An BD

Then you should be able to tweak one of the answers linked to above by Dima to get the last two or three words, then add in a condition to ignore the last three characters if they are " BD"

Try: =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),300)),"BD",)

Assuming no version constraints per your tags, to return the antepenultimate and penultimate substrings, you can use:
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,TAKE(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),-1),-2))

and fill down.

If you have Windows Excel 2013 or later, you could use:
=FILTERXML(
    "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
    "//s[last()-2]"
) & " " &
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", "</s><s>") &
            "</s></t>",
        "//s[last()-1]"
    )


I assumed that since the didn't have TEXTAFER() available (per the OP) that they therefore wouldn't have the other recent text functions.

@MaxR That's why I also supplied the FILTERXML option.

Pls. try this formula
=MID(A15,LARGE(IFERROR(FIND("!!",SUBSTITUTE(A15," ","!!"&ROW(1:20),ROW(1:20))),0),3)+1,LARGE(IFERROR(FIND("!!",SUBSTITUTE(A15," ","!!"&ROW(1:20),ROW(1:20))),0),1)-LARGE(IFERROR(FIND("!!",SUBSTITUTE(A15," ","!!"&ROW(1:20),ROW(1:20))),0),3)-1)

This works for 20 spaces and assumed there are no two !! in the string.


You could try something like this:


=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),300))


Alternatively, for MS365 users:


=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A5," ",-3)," ",-1)



I had to actually work through this in Excel to see what you did...  That's pretty sneaky!

There's a trick to finding out how many instances of spaces are in a cell.  In my examples, assume the original text is in A2 as shown in your sample:
LEN( A2 ) will equal 30.
SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") will remove all the spaces, so LEN( SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") ) will equal 23.  I now know there are 7 spaces.  (30 - 23)
LEN(A2) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") will equal 7 spaces, which means I want everything to the right of the FIFTH ( 7 - 3 + 1 ) space.
So, let me use that resulting number, FIVE in this case, to substitute an un-used character in the place of the 5th space:
SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-3+1) will result in:
22, 29 CHIÊU LIÊU TĐH@DĨ AN BD
The @ sign is in position 22, so the RIGHT( LEN(A2) - 22 ) will result in:
DĨ AN BD
So where you end up to get all that in one formula is:
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-3+1)))
or the same formula more easily pasted:
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-3+1)))

Note:
The number "3" in this formula is the number of "last N words" you want to get off the end, so that can be replaced if another number of words is needed.  Or it can be made dynamic as well.
Note 2:
If you are lucky enough to have access to the LET function and are used to using the alt-enter way of entering long formulas, you get:
=LET(
length, LEN(A2),
spaceCount, length-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2," ","")),
spaceToMark, spaceCount - 3 + 1,
markedString, SUBSTITUTE($A$2," ","@", spaceToMark ),
splitLocation, FIND("@",markedString),
RIGHT(A2, length - splitLocation)
)

